# Getting result from a database sequence in Slick 3.0.0

Tags: slick-3.0

I am trying to get the result of a query which is executed as a part of a sequence of actions passed as a parameter to DBIO.sequence() method of Slick 3.0. Below is the code snippet for the same.

```
val query = for {
 (tt, th) <- tmpTrades join TableQuery[TrdHeader] on (_.tradeNum === _.tradeNum)
 } yield (tt.tradeNum, th.internalInd, th.tradeStatusInd, th.tradeDt,   th.tradeInputDt, th.lastModifyDt)

val queryAction = query.result

val actions = Seq(tmpTrades.schema.create, tmpTrades ++= trades.toSeq: _*, queryAction, tmpTrades.schema.drop)

val resultFuture = db.run(DBIO.sequence(actions))
```

I want the result of DBIO.sequence(actions) as a tuple of six attributes corresponding to the yield clause of the query and assign it to resultFuture variable. How can I achieve the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `flatMap` instead of `DBIO.sequence`:

```scala
val myAction = tmpTrades.schema.create.flatMap { _ =>
  tmpTrades ++= trades.toSeq
}.flatMap { _ =>
  queryAction
}.flatMap { queryResult =>
  // Return the result at the end.
  tmpTrades.schema.drop.map { _ => queryResult }
}

db.run(myAction.transactionally)
```

Or the same thing as a `for-yield`:

```scala
val myAction = for {
  _ <- tmpTrades.schema.create
  _ <- (tmpTrades ++= trades.toSeq)
  queryResult <- queryAction
  _ <- tmpTrades.schema.drop
} yield queryResult

db.run(myAction.transactionally)
```

Comment: and finally, to print the results: `val result = db.run(myAction.transactionally)` which is printed using:
`result.foreach(println)` and if inside a REPL (not production code) you can block, waiting for the println with: `Await.ready(result, Duration.Inf)`